# Toggle watch on/off in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, watch

Is it possible to toggle a watch on/off in a simple way or signal that the watch should/shouldn't run right now? I know that I can unregister a watch, but how can I reregister it?

In my case I have a hiearchical select lists and when the parent select option changes a watch resets the child selection. This works fine when selecting options using the select lists, however when trying to assign values of the select options for both parent and child the watch of the parent kicks in and resets the child option.

I've put up a plunker that demonstrates this. Try select values from the list, then click loadValues

http://plnkr.co/edit/FbSff2?p=preview

This might the wrong way of doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't 100% understand why you are trying to watch and un-watch the values....

I modified your plunk and it all seems to work great.  I added an extra `ngChange` function to watch for the parent select and then erase the child from the `userSelection` and removed all the `$watch` functions.

http://www.plnkr.co/edit/7PJeja?p=preview

Again, I don't understand why you are trying to watch the variables, because you definitely don't need that to do what you are trying to do....  If you have another scenario where you need to register/unregister a watch, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for that, using ng-change seems to do the trick. This was actually what I was after. It also shows how fresh I'm to AngularJS.

Comment: Not a problem. I have only done a few apps myself soo am relatively new. In my experience so far, I have only ever used $watch for logging and debugging. But I am sure it has its place.